# Connecting from Android to Raspberry Pi Zero thru USB

Tags: usb, ssh, pi-zero-w, android

How can I connect from an Android phone into my Raspberry Pi Zero through the USB cable?
Very similar to this question [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=182273)

I can connect to my RpiZero through a usb cable on my macbook with no issues, it's only the Android that does not work.

Here's is the interface on the Mac that I connect through

```
en8: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
     options=6407<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
     ether 3e:bb:7d:d4:7a:82 
     inet6 fe80::1caf:45a3:e6aa:b333%en8 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x18 
     inet 192.168.42.129 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.42.255
     nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
     media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
     status: active
```

Here's the interface on the raspberry pi zero that I connect through.

```
usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.42.42  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
    inet6 fe80::c1d:4cff:feef:bbd0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 0e:1d:4c:ef:bb:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 262  bytes 36418 (35.5 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 134  bytes 23282 (22.7 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here's the rndis0 interface on my Android that is created when USB tethering is enabled:

```
rndis0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.42.129  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
```

However, when I connect both Rpi and android together via usb cable (male mini USB to female USB connector and male USB to male USB C), and run nmap on the Android phone, I can't see the Rpi on the network

```
~ $ nmap 192.168.42.*
  Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-07-09 18:49 PDT
  Nmap scan report for 192.168.42.129
  Host is up (0.0029s latency). Not shown: 999 closed tcp ports (conn-refused)
  PORT STATE SERVICE 
  53/tcp open  domain 
  Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (1 host up) scanned in 8.85 seconds
```

I've double checked that the USB cables can transfer data. What am I missing here? Tutorials online make it seem pretty simple to connect Android -> Rpi.

Comment: which one is the USB host?

Comment: The Android phone should be the USB host, as the rpi is the slave when it is connected to the computer via usb

Comment: https://ten0s.github.io/blog/2020/02/22/raspberrypi-static-ip-address-for-android-usb-tethering
This guide also seems relevant, my phone has the ip 192.168.42.129 too, but my pi doesn't have the dhcpcd service